# RMarkdown fails to render awesome-cv with bibliography_entries()

Tags: r-markdown, tinytex

I am trying to maintain my CV with RMarkdown, vitae, and tinytex. I had it working back in October, 2023, but now it fails to render if I include a bibtex file using `bibliography_entries("mypubs.bib")`. This happens even if I just open the awesome-cv template in RStudio. If I remove the bibliography block (line 60-66 in the template .Rmd), then the CV renders as expected and I can even change things like font type or colour in the .cls file. However, if I include the bibliography block, I get an error that says `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`. I am not fluent in LaTeX, but I know the `\item` is used in a list but when looking at the awesome-cv.cls file I can't seem to even find the section dealing with the bibliography, let alone an incomplete list.

This error starting occurring recently so perhaps it has something to do with the update to R 4.3.2 (Eye Holes). Has anyone else experienced this? I'm running `tinytex v0.49` and `vitae v0.5.4`, which I think are the most recent.

Thanks for any advice,
Jeremy

Comment: I have looked through some of the suggested related questions but none of them are addressing my issue. I have texlive and TinyTex installed, and I force the tlmgr path with `options(tinytex.tlmgr.path = "~/bin/tlmgr")` so as far as I know, it is not an issue with missing packages

Comment: It seems this is an issue between `vitae` and `pandoc` and it all started with pandoc 3.1.8 which may explain why your PDF won't compile after October (assuming pandoc got updated on your system).

Check the related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/issues/246. Maybe it will help if you switch to dev version of the package `remotes::install_github("mitchelloharawild/vitae")`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that was helpful. However, it seems to have brought to light another issue with my setup. In RStudio, the pandoc version is 0.2.0 but if I run `pandoc --version` in a terminal (I'm on Ubuntu 22.04) it says I'm on 2.9.2.1. Is it possible that the tlmgr is going to a separate repository to use pandoc, instead of using what is installed on my system?

Comment: It seems my system is a bit of a mess. In RStudio, `packageVersion("pandoc")` outputs `0.2.0` and `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` outputs `3.1.1` (which I guess is where the bibliography issue is coming from). In the terminal, I get the output above `2.9.2.1`. It seems I might be at a point where I just need to uninstall everything and start fresh....

Comment: Confusion comes from the fact that there is both system-wide installation of pandoc binaries and R package `pandoc` which maintains other version of `pandoc` to be used by knitr and RStudio. Check the `pandoc` R package manual, maybe you can uninstall or upgrade different pandoc installations. Version 2.x.x and 3.x.x refer to the pandoc binaries and 0.x.x are probably versions of the R package pandoc (not that relevant).

Comment: The problem was solved even easier than that by downgrading the `vitae` package to 0.5.3. https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/issues/248#issuecomment-1879717908