# Unable to render vitae package template rmd files to a PDF format:

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

Firstly I'd like to say that I'm new to R and R markdown. I wanted to play around with a CV template from the vitae package so I installed the package and loaded it.

Next, I picked one of them (all of them don't work) and clicked the knit button to render a PDF file. I'm following the Google Analytics course and it says that this template's default output is PDF, so all you have to do is click knit.

When I do that I get an error related to LaTeX:

```
processing file: Untitled.Rmd
                                                                                                            
output file: Untitled.knit.md

"D:/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Untitled.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Untitled.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\ilana\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\ilana\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --template "C:\Users\ilana\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\vitae\rmarkdown\templates\awesomecv\resources\awesome-cv.tex" --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine xelatex --lua-filter "C:/Users/ilana/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/vitae/multiple-bibliographies.lua" --variable page_total=TRUE --variable show_footer=TRUE 
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Untitled.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Untitled.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

The weird thing is that the output of the error keeps changing every time I try to render. For example, this is the output when I ran it another time:

```
  |............                                        |  22% [setup]          

processing file: test.Rmd
                                                                                                            
"D:/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\ilana\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\ilana\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --embed-resources --standalone --template "C:\Users\ilana\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.3\vitae\rmarkdown\templates\twentyseconds\resources\twentysecondstemplate.tex" --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --lua-filter "C:/Users/ilana/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/vitae/multiple-bibliographies.lua" 
output file: test.knit.md

texlive-scripts package not found (?!), skipping revision consistency check
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: textpos [5k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/Users/ilana/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr.pl: command log updated: C:/Users/ilana/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
texlive-scripts package not found (?!), skipping revision consistency check
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: marvosym [131k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running updmap-sys ...

tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/Users/ilana/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr.pl: command log updated: C:/Users/ilana/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
tlmgr.pl: updmap-sys failed (status 1), output:
...\ilana\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:941: ...\ilana\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:864: no appropriate script or program found: updmap
tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

I did install the tinytex distribution using the following:

```
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it as well but that didn't help as well. I searched the forums but the suggestions were mainly about tinytex which I already installed, so I'm not sure what to do. Btw, rendering to PDF format **does** work for me when I create a new rmd file, but not when using a template from the vitae package. I tried using another package and it didn't work either, so basically the error occurs on rmd templates.

I'd appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be related
[RMarkdown fails to render awesome-cv with bibliography_entries()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77747954/rmarkdown-fails-to-render-awesome-cv-with-bibliography-entries)

It appears to be a bug in the vitae package

Some users had success reverting to [version 0.5.3](https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/issues/248#issuecomment-1879717908)

Comment: Confirmed that this works with RStudio 2023.06.0 on MacOS 14.2.1 - it now renders the default CV correctly

    require(devtools)
    install_version("vitae", version = "0.5.3")